# Como mostrar somente um resultado de uma coluna específica [MSSQL]

Tags: sql-server

Tenho a seguinte QUERY:

```
 select id_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto,
           id_planta_re,
           tbl_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto.re,
           ponto_saldo_atual,
           convert(varchar(10),vecto_ponto,121)
      from tbl_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto INNER JOIN tbl_usuario aa ON aa.re = tbl_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto.re 
     where venceu = '2'
               and id_planta_re in ('100','110')
       and ponto_saldo_atual > 0
       and aa.status = '1'
       and (zerou is null or zerou = 'N')
```

Onde o resultado é parecido com a linha abaixo:

4803    100 **100363**      801.00  NULL

8202    110 **100363**      40.00   NULL

O problema é que ele repete o "RE" (número em negrito). O que eu gostaria era que mostrasse somente uma linha, não importando a linha que vai mostrar, desde que mostre 1 resultado para cada "RE"

É possível?

Obrigado

Comment: Já tentou botando um LIMIT 1 no final de query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neste caso, você precisa usar a cláusula GROUP BY, que agrupa o resultado por uma parametrização

As regras podem mudar dependendo do seu SGBP, mas por vias gerais ficaria assim:

```
 select MAX(id_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto) AS id_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto,
           MAX(id_planta_re) AS id_planta_re,
           tbl_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto.re,
           MAX(ponto_saldo_atual) AS ponto_saldo_atual,
           convert(varchar(10),MAX(vecto_ponto),121)
      from tbl_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto INNER JOIN tbl_usuario aa ON aa.re = tbl_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto.re 
     where venceu = '2'
               and id_planta_re in ('100','110')
       and ponto_saldo_atual > 0
       and aa.status = '1'
       and (zerou is null or zerou = 'N')
group by id_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto, id_planta_re, tbl_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto.re, ponto_saldo_atual, vecto_ponto
```

Você pode ler mais sobre group by aqui: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

O exemplo acima foi incluído o comando MAX para ser compatível com SQL Server.

Documentação da cláusula GROUP BY do SQL Server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms177673(v=sql.120).aspx

Outra solução! Seria fazer com sub-select no WHERE utilizando o EXISTS, já que seu JOIN você utiliza para filtro:

```
SELECT
    id_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto,
    id_planta_re,
    re,
    ponto_saldo_atual,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), vecto_ponto, 121) AS vecto_ponto
FROM
    tbl_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto
WHERE
    (venceu = '2')
    AND (id_planta_re in ('100','110'))
    AND (ponto_saldo_atual > 0)
    AND EXISTS (
      SELECT
        aa.re
      FROM
        tbl_usuario AS aa
      WHERE
        (aa.re = tbl_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto.re)
        AND (aa.status = '1')
    )
    AND (
      (zerou IS null)
      OR (zerou = 'N')
    );
```

Documentação do EXISTS: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/exists-transact-sql

Comment: Diego, já havia tentado isso antes e dá o erro: Column 'tbl_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto.id_cc_ponto_saldo_vecto' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Neste caso, é porque seu SGBD exige que todas colunas na cláusula SELECT estejam no GROUP BY, o SQL Server é assim por exemplo. Neste caso precisa incluir todas colunas no GROUP BY e depois no SELECT vc trata para extrair apenas um valor, por exemplo, com o comando MAX, vou alterar o exemplo acima

Comment: Quando você incluiu o MAX, deu certo. No caso, você está incluindo todas as minhas colunas dentro de um GROUP BY, é isso? Toda vez que eu quiser fazer um GROUP BY eu sempre tenho que fazer isso em todas as colunas, certo?

Comment: @user2287892 Exatamente! no exemplo eu esqueci de incluir as colunas no GROUP BY, desculpe, mas já vou editar o exemplo

Comment: Tudo isso depende na verdade da regra de negócio que você quer aplicar. O resultado do select gerou linhas duplicadas pois o relacionamento feito no _JOIN_ foi com um campo só (re) e não foi o suficiente para uma "amarração" de um para um.Isso causou o retorno de mais de um registro para o a chave 100363.No caso do _GROUP BY_ , ele irá agrupar uma ou N colunas e as colunas não agrupadas devem receber uma função, por exemplo o MAX, MIN, COUNT, SUM, etc. Com isso você deve aplicar a sua regra de negócio fazendo a seguinte pergunta "como quero que as colunas **não agrupadas** sejam apresentadas?"